# Can we use the Select query to get the vertex data using JDBC Driver in Java

Tags: java, jdbc, tigergraph

I am trying to run select statement for tigerGraph using JDBC Driver for JAVA but getting java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported dbtable: InfectionCase Error. Is select statement supported by tigerGraph using JDBC or is there any other way to execute Select Statement.

```
try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
        String query = "select * From InfectionCase where id == \"Hansarang Convalescent Hospital\"";
        System.out.println("Running :" + query);
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(query);
        System.out.println(rs.toString());
        do {
            java.sql.ResultSetMetaData metaData = rs.getMetaData();
            System.out.println("Table: " + metaData.getCatalogName(1));
            System.out.print(metaData.getColumnName(1));
            for (int i = 2; i <= metaData.getColumnCount(); ++i) {
                System.out.print("\t" + metaData.getColumnName(i));
            }

java.sql.SQLException: Unsupported dbtable: InfectionCase
at com.tigergraph.jdbc.restpp.driver.QueryParser.<init>(QueryParser.java:629)
at com.tigergraph.jdbc.restpp.RestppStatement.execute(RestppStatement.java:41)
at com.tigergraph.jdbc.restpp.RestppStatement.executeQuery(RestppStatement.java:35)
at com.prissoft.connection.GraphJSON.selectStatementUsingSQL(GraphJSON.java:145)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Not the main error, but apostrophe, single quote, for values and single = for equality:`"select * from InfectionCase where id = 'Hansarang Convalescent Hospital'"`. You might use `con.getMetaData()` and query all table names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch vertex instances from TigerGraph you need to use a different syntax as the `SELECT` statement is not supported in the JDBC driver:

```
try (Connection con = getConnection()) {
    String query = "get vertex(InfectionCase, \"Hansarang Convalescent Hospital\")";
    <more statements>
}
```

You can use this `get vertex(vertex_type)` syntax to get a single vertex by primary ID or get a set of vertices (optionally filtered, sorted and limited). See the [documentation](https://github.com/tigergraph/ecosys/tree/master/tools/etl/tg-jdbc-driver#supported-queries-and-syntax) on this.

I personally think that it is better to access TigerGraph via the [REST API](https://docs.tigergraph.com/tigergraph-server/current/api/) than using the JDBC driver. JDBC was designed for relation databases and thus it expects tabular data. The graph is not tabular, it's a data network. So, what you normally get out of a TigerGraph statement or query execution is a JSON document describing a subgraph: vertices and edges. This output can be flattened into rows and columns, but then you get a lesser image of the graph: a 2D projection of a 3D (or rather: a multi-dimensional) data set.

Another note: fetching individual vertices and edges, or even sets of these via JDBC calls (like above) or via the built-in REST endpoints (like `http://localhost:9000/graph/MyGrah/vertices/InfectionCase/Hansarang+Convalescent+Hospital`) is not the most efficient use of TigerGraph. Surely, sometimes you just need a set of vertices to list in an app or visualise a graph. The real power comes from developing [queries](https://docs.tigergraph.com/gsql-ref/current/tutorials/gsql-101/parameterized-gsql-query), TigerGraph's "stored procedures" that can execute even very complex and sophisticated graph algorithms like [PageRank](https://github.com/tigergraph/gsql-graph-algorithms/tree/master/algorithms/Centrality/pagerank) or [Louvain community detection](https://github.com/tigergraph/gsql-graph-algorithms/tree/master/algorithms/Community/louvain) inside the graph very fast, in a parallelised fashion.